# Nginx prevent access to ports that are used by my app

Tags: nginx

I need to create a redirection form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000 (myIP:8000) to example.com

I also need to redirect from www.example.com to example.com

My current set-up has a production app and a dev app:

Prod:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Staging/dev:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dev.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            # Password protect dev. subdomain
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    }
}
```

Nginx is something very new to me and I'm quite lost.

Comment: Managed to solve it with a firewall. Did a `sudo ufw enable` and `sudo ufw allow 80` which blocked all other ports. If you're doing it, don't forget to allow SSH connection `sudo ufw allow OpenSSH`

Comment: Please add that as an answer and mark it as accepted (after 2 days this is possible), so that it is clear that this problem has been solved.

Comment: @CamilStaps thanks, will do that